# Loading .dat files from sub folders

Tags: matlab, file, load, subdirectory

I have the following code;
`clear
clc
for n = 1:20
    foldername = sprintf('G:\\Protable Hard Drive\\PHD Hard Drive\\Experimental Data\\Bulkrename Trial\\TSR7.85\\Center Left P%d\\0.66D', n)
    dir(foldername)
    datfiles = dir(fullfile('.', 'foldername', '*.dat'))
end`

From this I can access the subfolder 0.66D which is in a parent folder called Center Left P%d with %d ranging from 1 to 20. With the `dir` command I can clearly see the files of each sub folder listed in the command window; `foldername =

G:\Protable Hard Drive\PHD Hard Drive\Experimental Data\Bulkrename Trial\TSR7.85\Center Left P1\0.66D

.             0_66D.R0027   0_66D.S0017   0_66D.T0007   0_66D.T0035   0_66D.V0025   POINT775.dat
..            0_66D.R0028   0_66D.S0018   0_66D.T0008   0_66D.T0036   0_66D.V0026   POINT776.dat
0_66D.R0001   0_66D.R0029   0_66D.S0019   0_66D.T0009   0_66D.T0037   0_66D.V0027   POINT777.dat
0_66D.R0002   0_66D.R0030   0_66D.S0020   0_66D.T0010   0_66D.T0038   0_66D.V0028   POINT778.dat
0_66D.R0003   0_66D.R0031   0_66D.S0021   0_66D.T0011   0_66D.V0001   0_66D.V0029   POINT779.dat
0_66D.R0004   0_66D.R0032   0_66D.S0022   0_66D.T0012   0_66D.V0002   0_66D.V0030   POINT780.dat
0_66D.R0005   0_66D.R0033   0_66D.S0023   0_66D.T0013   0_66D.V0003   0_66D.V0031   POINT781.dat
0_66D.R0006   0_66D.R0034   0_66D.S0024   0_66D.T0014   0_66D.V0004   0_66D.V0032   POINT782.dat
0_66D.R0007   0_66D.R0035   0_66D.S0025   0_66D.T0015   0_66D.V0005   0_66D.V0033   POINT783.dat
0_66D.R0008   0_66D.R0036   0_66D.S0026   0_66D.T0016   0_66D.V0006   0_66D.V0034   POINT784.dat
0_66D.R0009   0_66D.R0037   0_66D.S0027   0_66D.T0017   0_66D.V0007   0_66D.V0035   POINT785.dat
0_66D.R0010   0_66D.R0038   0_66D.S0028   0_66D.T0018   0_66D.V0008   0_66D.V0036   POINT786.dat
0_66D.R0011   0_66D.S0001   0_66D.S0029   0_66D.T0019   0_66D.V0009   0_66D.V0037   POINT787.dat
0_66D.R0012   0_66D.S0002   0_66D.S0030   0_66D.T0020   0_66D.V0010   0_66D.V0038   POINT788.dat
0_66D.R0013   0_66D.S0003   0_66D.S0031   0_66D.T0021   0_66D.V0011   POINT761.dat  POINT789.dat
0_66D.R0014   0_66D.S0004   0_66D.S0032   0_66D.T0022   0_66D.V0012   POINT762.dat  POINT790.dat
0_66D.R0015   0_66D.S0005   0_66D.S0033   0_66D.T0023   0_66D.V0013   POINT763.dat  POINT791.dat
0_66D.R0016   0_66D.S0006   0_66D.S0034   0_66D.T0024   0_66D.V0014   POINT764.dat  POINT792.dat
0_66D.R0017   0_66D.S0007   0_66D.S0035   0_66D.T0025   0_66D.V0015   POINT765.dat  POINT793.dat
0_66D.R0018   0_66D.S0008   0_66D.S0036   0_66D.T0026   0_66D.V0016   POINT766.dat  POINT794.dat
0_66D.R0019   0_66D.S0009   0_66D.S0037   0_66D.T0027   0_66D.V0017   POINT767.dat  POINT795.dat
0_66D.R0020   0_66D.S0010   0_66D.S0038   0_66D.T0028   0_66D.V0018   POINT768.dat  POINT796.dat
0_66D.R0021   0_66D.S0011   0_66D.T0001   0_66D.T0029   0_66D.V0019   POINT769.dat  POINT797.dat
0_66D.R0022   0_66D.S0012   0_66D.T0002   0_66D.T0030   0_66D.V0020   POINT770.dat  POINT798.dat
0_66D.R0023   0_66D.S0013   0_66D.T0003   0_66D.T0031   0_66D.V0021   POINT771.dat  master.bak
0_66D.R0024   0_66D.S0014   0_66D.T0004   0_66D.T0032   0_66D.V0022   POINT772.dat  vtmp.000
0_66D.R0025   0_66D.S0015   0_66D.T0005   0_66D.T0033   0_66D.V0023   POINT773.dat  vtmp.001
0_66D.R0026   0_66D.S0016   0_66D.T0006   0_66D.T0034   0_66D.V0024   POINT774.dat  `

However when I try to load all the .dat files within each subfolder into my workspace, I get the following error; `datfiles =

0x1 struct array with fields:

```
name
date
bytes
isdir
datenum`
```

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?
Regards,
Jerry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the output of `fullfile('.', 'foldername', '*.dat')`, there are no files in `.\foldername\*.dat`. `foldername` is a variable, don't use quotation marks, and the leading `.` does not make sense when combined with an absolute path.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for the quick reply. When I use `datfiles = fullfile(foldername, '*.dat')` I get an output of datafiles = G:\Protable Hard Drive\PHD Hard Drive\Experimental Data\Bulkrename Trial\TSR7.85\Center Left P20\0.66D\*.dat. How do I get a list of all the .dat files in each subfolder so that I can start processing them?

Comment: My mistake Daniel. I ran the following `clear
clc
for n = 1:20
    foldername = sprintf('G:\\Protable Hard Drive\\PHD Hard Drive\\Experimental Data\\Bulkrename Trial\\TSR7.85\\Center Left P%d\\0.66D', n)
    dir(foldername)
    datfiles = dir( fullfile(foldername, '*.dat'))
    
end` and i got datfiles =38x1 which is correct as there are 38 .dat files in each subfolder. But how do I create a list of all the .dat files in all the subfolders. There should be 1502 of them. Sorry about this but I am relatively new to matlab. Regards, Jerry

Comment: @Jerry `dir` will not search subdirectories. There are a number of functions on the MATLAB File Exchange that will do this for you, such as [subdir](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15859-subdir--a-recursive-file-search), which returns information in the same format as `dir`. Alternatively, you could create your own. For example, you could use `[~, list]=system('dir /S /B *.dat');` and parse `list` with a regular expression.